# Cryptic OpenCv error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to detect humans in images using the haarcascade full body algorithm using OpenCv in Python.

when i consider using it on a single image, I face no issues.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

body_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(r'...\haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
image = cv.imread(r'...\image.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
body = body_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.01, 4)
for (x,y,w,h) in body:
    cv.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
```

But, when I try to use the same program and iterate over several images at once, I get a cryptic OpenCv error. I have some images in a folder and I want to separate images with humans in them from those that don't. I wrote the following:

```
import os

for file in os.walk(r'...\Folder'):
    file=str(file)
    im=cv.imread(file)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    body = body_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.01, 4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in body:
        cv.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
    if(body.size >= 0):
        print('okay') 
    else:
        print('Not okay')
```

But I get the following error :

`error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'`

for the line `gray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

I am unable to understand what the error is and why the same code that works when taking individual images is working but not the case when iterating through a folder. Do I need to resize the images ?

Also, I tried with keeping just one image in the folder, on which the code had worked before, still doesn't work.

Comment: You probably have a duff jpg, you should print the file name and test just that specific file

Comment: @EdChum The same image, when inside the folder and ran through the first code, has no issues. But when I use the second code, it shows the error

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other files in that folder? You should still print the full file path, check whether `im` is `None`, and also the shape of the image

Comment: I am sure that there are no other files in the folder. In fact, like I said, I checked the image, while inside the folder, with the first code and it works. Running through the second code, where only directory is mentioned, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Doc, it seems like OpenCV fails to locate the image. What happens if you're using full paths instead of relative ones? (and what are the three dots there "..." ?)
please dump the file that you read back to disc for debugging purposes and I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: The dots "..." are simply the path, I use the full C:\users\...\filename in the actual code. Just for representation I used dots here. Also, I simply search "pedestrian" on Google and use any random image with a few people in them. Like I said, it all works fine with the first code, the problem occurs in the second code.